# loading data into combo object with sql query result in Java

Tags: java, mysql, combobox

I would like to load a combo object with a result of sql query. I do not know how to convert List into String[]. 
My source is bellow:

```
public static void loadJadlospis() {
    List<String[]> ans1= null;
    String[] comboData=null;

    MySQL.Connect();
    ans1 = MySQL.sqlQuery("SELECT NazwaJadlospisu FROM Jadlospis GROUP BY NazwaJadlospisu");
    MySQL.Close();

    int a=0;
    for( String[] row: ans1 ){
        a=a+1;
        System.out.print( row[0] );
        comboData[a]=(row[0] + ",");
    }
    combo.setItems(comboData);  
}
```

This code does not work. I got an error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
Could you please give me any suggestions on how to have it working?

---

UPDATE1:
Bellow you can see MySQL.sqlQuery source:

```
public static List<String[]> sqlQuery(String sql){
    List<String[]> table= new ArrayList<>();

    try{
        state = con.createStatement();
        result = state.executeQuery(sql);
        int nCol = result.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        while(result.next()){
            String[] row = new String[nCol];
            for( int iCol = 1; iCol <= nCol; iCol++ ){
                    Object obj = result.getObject( iCol );
                    row[iCol-1] = (obj == null) ?null:obj.toString();
                }
            table.add( row );
            }    
        }
    catch(SQLException e){
        System.err.println("Query error. " +e);
        }
    catch(NullPointerException e){
        System.err.println("Element not found." +e);
        }
    return table;
    }
```

---

UPDATE 2

I use the following code to check the ans1:

```
List<String[]> ans1= null;


MySQL.Connect();
ans1 = MySQL.sqlQuery("SELECT NazwaJadlospisu FROM Jadlospis GROUP BY NazwaJadlospisu");
for( String[] row: ans1 ){
    System.out.print( row[0] );
    System.out.println();
}
MySQL.Close();
```

It prints this:

```
Successfully connected to database. 
dieta 1500 kcal 
dieta testowa1 
test1 
Database closed successfully.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do in the following manner. Here I assume that `ans1` is having a list of String type values and you can convert list to strings like `list.toArray(new String[0])`.

```
public static void loadJadlospis() {
    List<String[]> ans1= null;
    MySQL.Connect();
    ans1 = MySQL.sqlQuery("SELECT NazwaJadlospisu FROM Jadlospis GROUP BY NazwaJadlospisu");
    MySQL.Close();
    List<String> rowsList = new ArrayList<>()   
    for(String[] rows: ans1) {
      for(String str: rows) {
         rowsList.add(str);
       }
    }   
    String[] comboData=rowsList.toArray(new String[0]);
    combo.setItems(comboData);  
}
```

Comment: I did as you suggested and got the following error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException: arraycopy: element type mismatch: can not cast one of the elements of java.lang.Object[] to the type of the destination array, java.lang.String

Comment: I got it, your sql query is not returning a list of string, it is returning a list of objects. You can check the query in your database editor.

Comment: I will copy/paste MySQL.sqlQuery method

Comment: Now I got this error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Print this value `ans1`, is it returning any value from database query ?

Comment: Yes, it does, I will update the post with the source

Comment: I have printed out comboData[0]... [1] and [2] and it looks that data is there, but I have no idea why I got an error.

Comment: OK. I got it working! Your solution was perfect. The problem was that I have declared combo in different method. Anyway.. this is solved now with your big help. Thank you!